# MongoDB workaround for blocking connection or change timeout for connecting. [C++]

Tags: c++, mongodb

Is there a way to change the C++ connection timeout? as per this bug report, it seems not. But it says there is a simple workaround, and I'm not sure what.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3983

I have autoreconnect on, and when the connection to the server goes down, it seems like the whole application hangs for 5s while it tries to reconnect. What would be the solution? is there a way to do a non-blocking `connect` call? I do check if the connection is open,

```
if(conn->isStillConnected ()){
        try {
            conn->insert(ns, obj, flags);
            std::string e = conn->getLastError();
            if( !e.empty() ) { 
                std::string err = "Insert failed: ";
                ...
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (mongo::DBException& e) {
            ...
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see, I want to just skip updates/inserts if the connection is bad without blocking the main thread.

I can implement threading, but the whole software package I'm working with doesn't seem to use them, and I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: This posting gets a lot of traffic, but describes how to build the now-officially-out-of-date "Legacy C++" Driver. The Legacy C++ driver has been obsoleted by the new C++11 driver. The new C++11 driver should be the first choice when writing a client application in C++ that will communicate with MongoDB. Information on how to build the new C++11 driver is available here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-(New-Driver)

Unfortunately the client code in the server will not change (for the time being). However you can use the C++ driver that we have extracted from the server and refactor your code a bit to make this work for you. The extracted driver is called the "legacy" driver and we have made some improvements to the usability of it.

[Legacy C++ Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/tree/legacy)

This version of the driver now has a default write concern of "Acknowledged" meaning that you can simply try the write operation you want to do and it will either succeed OR throw an error. This means that you do not need to call getLastError() your self.

You can read more about the [Acknowledged write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#acknowledged) or [breaking changes in the new driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Breaking%20changes%20between%2026compat%20and%20legacy). Specifically the behavior changes are [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Breaking%20changes%20between%2026compat%20and%20legacy#behavior-changes).

However, there is currently no option in the legacy C++ driver to configure a connect timeout and unfortunately we are unlikely to add one and change the networking code at this point.

My suggestion would be to not use isStillConnected OR autoreconnect and simply try the operation (which by default now requires a response in the legacy driver).

```
bool doInsert(const std::string& ns, const BSONObj& obj, int flags) {
    try {
        conn->insert(ns, obj, flags);
    }
    catch (mongo::OperationException& e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't it still cause the program to halt till it tries to connect? That is the problem, and was hoping there's a simple solution than using threading..